# pass null parameter if image not exist

Tags: c#, image, winforms

I have the following code to store image in database

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {   
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            pboxImage.Image.Save(ms, pboxImage.Image.RawFormat);
            byte[] byteimage = ms.ToArray();  

            AddClient.ADD_CLIENT(txtName.Text, byteimage);   
            MessageBox.Show("add successfuly);
        }
```

AddClient

```
public void ADD_CLIENT(string de_fullName, byte[] de_photo)
        {

            DAL.open();

            SqlParameter[] param = new SqlParameter[2];

            param[0] = new SqlParameter("@de_fullName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
            param[0].Value = de_fullName;


            if ( de_photo == null)
            {
                param[1] = new SqlParameter("@de_photo", SqlDbType.Binary);
                param[1].Value = DBNull.Value;
            }
            else
            {
                param[1] = new SqlParameter("@de_photo", SqlDbType.Binary);
                param[1].Value = de_photo;
            }


            DAL.ExecuteCommand("ADD_CLIENT", param);
            DAL.close();

        }
```

it works if `pboxImage` has image but when it has no photo it gives me an error

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object.'

Comment: Well, if `pboxImage.Image` is null (i.e. "when [`pboxImage`] has no photo"), what would you expect to happen when you try accessing `pboxImage.Image.RawFormat` (or later (in execution sequence) `pboxImage.Image.Save` for that matter)?

Comment: so how to edit my code to pass a null value in that case ?

Comment: *You* tell *me*. You know now what the problem is, you know how "branching execution paths" (if/else) work, so what would they look like, if put together? (Hint: *somewhere* there should probably be something like `if (pboxImage.Image == null) { [...] }`)